# Moq - Setup method with complex parameters

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to set up a mock of this interface:

```
public interface IAuthenticatedRequestService
    {
        HttpClient CreateHttpClientForJwt(Func<HttpResponseMessage, bool> isUnauthenticated, int timeoutSeconds);

        HttpClient CreateHttpClientForAccessToken(Func<HttpResponseMessage, bool> isUnauthenticated, int timeoutSeconds);
    }
```

This is one implementation of the method to setup that is in use and working:

```
public HttpClient CreateHttpClientForAccessToken(Func<HttpResponseMessage, bool> isUnauthenticated, int timeoutSeconds)
        {
            var client = Mvx.Resolve<IPlatformOperationProvider>().CreateHttpClient(timeoutSeconds);
            return new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpMessageHandler(this, client, AuthenticationUtils.AddAccessTokenToRequest, isUnauthenticated,_loggingService));
        }
```

This is one usage of the implemented method that is working:

```
var client = service.CreateHttpClientForAccessToken(x => x.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, CoreConstants.TimeoutMyDetails);
```

This is my unit test which sets up the mock:

```
    [Test]
            public async void TestIsLoggedInIsTrue()
            {
                //Arrange
                var authenticatedRequestService = new Mock<IAuthenticatedRequestService>();
                authenticatedRequestService.Setup(foo => foo.CreateHttpClientForAccessToken((It.IsAny<Func <HttpResponseMessage, bool>>())
                , 0
                        )).Returns(new HttpClient());

                var platformOperationProvider = new Mock<IPlatformOperationProvider>();
                platformOperationProvider.Setup(foo => foo.CreateHttpClient(1)).Returns(new HttpClient());

                Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IPlatformOperationProvider>(platformOperationProvider.Object);


                Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IAuthenticatedRequestService>(authenticatedRequestService.Object);

                var loggedInProvider = new LoggedInProvider(
                    new Mock<ISecuredSettings>().Object,
                    new Mock<ILoggingService>().Object
                    );

                //Act
                await loggedInProvider.SetUserAndToken(
                    new User(), 
                    new ApiAccessInfo("refresh token", "access token", "jwt")
                    );

                //Assert
                Assert.IsTrue(loggedInProvider.IsLoggedIn);
            }
```

This unit test has no errors, but the test fails (I think it is because I am passing it any HttpResponseMessage? And I need to somehow pass it HttpStatusCode.Accepted? How would I do that?

Take note of the usage of the method, how it passes HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, then can I do something like that with HttpStatusCode.Accepted?:

```
var client = service.CreateHttpClientForAccessToken(x => x.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, CoreConstants.TimeoutMyDetails);
```

**EDIT: To be clear, It is this line of code that I need to correct:**

```
authenticatedRequestService.Setup(foo => foo.CreateHttpClientForAccessToken((It.IsAny<Func <HttpResponseMessage, bool>>())
                    , 0
                            )).Returns(new HttpClient());
```

**EDIT: Whilst debugging the problem starts here (check the code comment after the `client` is created):**

```
    async Task<ServiceResponse> UpdateUserDetails()
            {
                // Have to late-resolve this otherwise we end up with a dependency loop
                var service = Mvx.Resolve<IAuthenticatedRequestService>();

                try
                {
                    var client = service.CreateHttpClientForAccessToken(x => x.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, CoreConstants.TimeoutMyDetails);

// here is the problem, the client is null after this line of code.

                    var user = _user;
```

**I have since found that it is not a Moq issue. MvvmCross is not registering the object to resolve correctly.**

**This line is not working:**

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IAuthenticatedRequestService>(authenticatedRequestService.Object);
```

**as this line creates an `AuthenticatedRequestService` but it is not the mock one that I made:**

```
var service = Mvx.Resolve<IAuthenticatedRequestService>();
```

**Here is some context of resolving the `AuthenticatedRequestService`**

```
async Task<ServiceResponse> UpdateUserDetails()
        {
            // Have to late-resolve this otherwise we end up with a dependency loop
            var service = Mvx.Resolve<IAuthenticatedRequestService>();

            try
            {
                var client = service.CreateHttpClientForAccessToken(x => x.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, CoreConstants.TimeoutMyDetails);

                var user = _user;

                var str = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(user.IdUrl));
                var newUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User.Json>(str);

                var token = _token;
                if (token != null)
```

Comment: You Assert a property of the instance loggedInProvider (of type LoggedInProvider) however. I can't se any declaration of that class in your sample. Can you provide a compiling sample?

Comment: @flo There is a LoggedInProvider instantiated in the original unit test, however I have pasted some more code using the LoggedInProvider from a passing unit test. Cheers

Comment: my hopes where, that might be able to shorten your sample to narrow the issue down :-)